# Url.Action and two variables

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have  `@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("GetTabData", new { page })`

and inside my js file I have ready to use `myTab` variable which I need to send together with page in above example.

How can I do that?

Update:
I'm using js variable to determine which tab is user click and based on that value I'm quering data. Now I have implemeted pagination which uses above generated link. With this in place my ajax call for sending activeTab is broken, I need to send this value together with page inside above Url.Action.

This is js variable which I use to send over ajax to determine which tab is user click

```
$(function () {
    var activeTab = null;
    $('#tabs .tabLink').click(function (event) {
        var activeTab = $(this).attr('href').split('-')[1];
        GetTabData(activeTab);        
    });
    GetTabData(ommitted on purpse)

});
```

Comment: Your question hardly makes sense. Could you try to reformulate it? What js file and what `myTab` variable are you talking about?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov question is updated.

Comment: I have the same problem...  @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("GetTabData", new { page })... will only pass the page variable... we also want to pass an additional variable

Answer (score 0):

I don't get the question clearly, but I am taking a guess here. Don't know if this is what you are looking for.

Note - You have `GetTabData` in both your javascript as well as cshtml code, I am hoping this is just coincidence, because the js function cannot be invoked via `@Url.Action` in this manner.

If you need to send two values as part of your URL, you could do it either in a RESTful way or have querystrings.

Option 1 -

```
Url.Action("GetTabData", new { page=2, tab="blah" })
```

Your corresponding controller action would look like

```
public ActionResult GetTabData(int page, string tab)
{
...
}
```

Option 2 - 
create a querystring and append it to the URL

```
/GetTabData?page=2&tab=blah
```

In this case the controller action would look like this

```
public ActionResult GetTabData()
{
    var params = Request.QueryString;
...
}
```